# sqlite3 database with python avoiding repetition

Tags: database, python-3.x, sqlite

> - Player (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT, Gender TEXT, Age INTEGER)
> - Scores (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Score TEXT, Date DATE, Time TIME)
> - Link (Player_ID, Score_ID)

I have a database for a snake game I am making, if a high score (20 highest scores are saved) is achieved the program asks the user to input its details to save them in this database, but if the same player achieves a high score it repeats in the database and it has a different primary key. How can I fix this? And how can I read from player table and scores tables  to display its data. Or if I only want to display the scores of only one player. This is what I have so far:

```
import sqlite3 
import time
import random


connection = sqlite3.connect('Test1.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

def create_Player_Table():
    cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Player (ID INTEGER PRIMARY 
     KEY, Name TEXT, Gender TEXT, Age INTEGER)')

def Insert_Player():
    ID = cursor.lastrowid
    Name = input("Enter name: ")
    Gender = input("Enter gender: ")
    Age = input("Enter age: ")
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Player (ID, Name, Gender, Age) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
              (ID, Name, Gender, Age))
    connection.commit()
    Player_ID = cursor.lastrowid
    return Player_ID


def create_Scores_Table():
    cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Scores (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Score TEXT, Date DATE, Time TIME)')

def Insert_Score():
    ID = cursor.lastrowid
    Score = random.randint(1,100000)
    Date = time.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
    Time = time.strftime("%X")
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Scores (ID, Score, Date, Time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
              (ID, Score, Date, Time))
    connection.commit()
    Score_ID = cursor.lastrowid
    return Score_ID

def create_Link_Table():
    cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Link (Player_ID, Score_ID, FOREIGN KEY (Player_ID) REFERENCES Player (ID), FOREIGN KEY (Score_ID) REFERENCES Scores (ID))')

def Insert_IDs():
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Link (Player_ID, Score_ID) VALUES (?, ?)",(Player_ID, Score_ID))
    connection.commit()

create_Player_Table()
create_Scores_Table()
create_Link_Table()
Player_ID = Insert_Player()
Score_ID = Insert_Score()
Insert_IDs()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the first stage in accomplishing what you want is to understand how to JOIN the tables. Central to this will be the **Link** table.

So you start with getting all rows from the link table along with the linked (related) data.

The following will assume, the following tables :-

#### Player Table :-

[image]

#### Scores Table :-

[image]

#### Link Table :-

[image]

- Note This may be a little more complex that you would have as some players are linked to the same scores. (e.g. players 1,2 and 4 are all linked/associated/related to score 3, which probably wouldn't be the case).

As such the following would do accomplish this :-

```
    SELECT * FROM Link JOIN Scores ON  Score_ID = Scores.ID JOIN Player ON Player_ID = Player.id
```

Which would produce :-

[image]

I think the above answers

> And how can I read from player table and scores tables to display its
>   data.

Adding `WHERE Player.id = 2` will restrict the result to Player 2 e.g.

```
    SELECT * FROM Link JOIN Scores ON  Score_ID = Scores.ID JOIN Player ON Player_ID = Player.id WHERE Player.id = 2
```

I think this answers

> if I only want to display the scores of only one player.

---

> if a high score (20 highest scores are saved) is achieved the program
>   asks the user to input its details to save them in this database, but
>   if the same player achieves a high score it repeats in the database
>   and it has a different primary key. How can I fix this?

Is a little more complex but first you want the Top x Scores per Play *(the examples use 2 as x instead of 20 for simplicity)*

You could obtain these for player **2** by Sorting (ordering) the results according to the **Score** column in Descending (**DESC**) order and **LIMIT**ing the rows returned to x (**2**) :-

```
    SELECT score FROM Link JOIN Scores ON  Score_ID = Scores.ID JOIN Player ON Player_ID = Player.id WHERE Player.id = 2 ORDER BY Score DESC LIMIT(2);
```

However, you would want the minimum value (if greater than this then add the score), unfortunately using SELECT MIN(score) ...... will get the minimum score *(100 for player 2 not the expected **1100**)*

Rather a compound SELECT is required that is SELECT MIN(Score) but only of the top x scores for the player (i.e as per the previous selection - so a select within a select is needed). This would be :-

```
     SELECT MIN(score) FROM (SELECT score FROM Link JOIN Scores ON  Score_ID = Scores.ID JOIN Player ON Player_ID = Player.id WHERE Player.id = 2 ORDER BY Score DESC LIMIT(2))
```

This results in :-

[image]

The final stage is to only extract the value and then insert a new row if the score is greater than the minimum  (assumes first lowest score is the score to keep). It might be easier to use `SELECT MIN(score) AS minscore` (i.e. add `AS minscore`) to rename the returned row to **`minscore`** rather than `MIN(score)`

---

However, you could then, with more complexity, use the above to provide the values for a `SELECT INSERT statement` i.e. it inserts data based upon the results from a SELECT. You can even use the SQLite Date and Time functions to supply the date and time values (assuming the current time).

First the above amended to include the date and time *([refer to - Date And Time Functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for formatting etc)*

So the above could be :-

```
SELECT MIN(score) as minscore, date('now') as datenow, time('now') as timenow FROM
    (
        SELECT score FROM Link 
            JOIN Scores ON Score_ID = Scores.ID 
            JOIN Player ON Player_ID = Player.id 
            WHERE Player.id = 2 /*<<< PLAYER THIS IS FOR */
            ORDER BY Score DESC
            LIMIT(2) /*<<< Number of scores to consider */
    )
```

This would result in :-

[image]

What is wanted now is to limit the above to only return a row if minscore is less than the score (or the score is greater than minscore). However, due to the way SQLIte determines  aggregates, WHERE minscore < ?????, has to be in a select in which the above select is wrapped.

An additional complexity is that minscore will be treated as a TEXT column so an SQLite CAST will be required to force it's usage as an integer.
The result is :-

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT MIN(score) as minscore, date('now') as datenow, time('now') as timenow FROM
        (
            SELECT score FROM Link 
                JOIN Scores ON Score_ID = Scores.ID 
                JOIN Player ON Player_ID = Player.id 
                WHERE Player.id = 2 /*<<< PLAYER THIS IS FOR */
                ORDER BY Score DESC
                LIMIT(2) /*<<< Number of scores to consider */
        ) 
    )
WHERE CAST(minscore AS INT) < 100 /*<<< SCORE to add or not if too small */
```

Nearly there, this is going to provide the data for the SELECT INSERT , so finally :-

```
INSERT INTO Scores (Score, Date, Time) 
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT MIN(score) as minscore, date('now') as datenow, time('now') as timenow FROM
        (
            SELECT score FROM Link 
                JOIN Scores ON Score_ID = Scores.ID 
                JOIN Player ON Player_ID = Player.id 
                WHERE Player.id = 2 /*<<< PLAYER THIS IS FOR */
                ORDER BY Score DESC
                LIMIT(2) /*<<< Number of scores to consider */
        ) 
    )
WHERE CAST(minscore AS INT) < 1200 /*<<< SCORE to add or not if too small */
```

Note! You would then get the ID (***Notice that the ID WAS NOT specified as a column, which would be the normal way to make use of an ID column***) and Insert an entry into the Link table. (I believe that this could also be done by utilising the `last_insert_rowid()` SQLite function, but I haven't tried that).

P.S. It may well be that the Link tables is superfluous. Perhaps you could store the respective player's id in the Scores table (this would simplify the above.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have another question. When a score higher than the minimum high score is achieved the program asks the user for his details, and if the user was already there it is repeated and I get two row of the same user but different ID. Sorry, I am new in sqlite3 python and THANK YOU

Comment: Also, I created the link table because player and score would be a many to many relationship, I created it to make it normalised and split it into two one to many relationships. BTW I get more marks the more complicated it is hahaha, but only if it is efficient

Comment: @Hammad You probably want a function/method that checks if a user exists that returns a boolean. This could be based upon `SELECT * FROM Player WHERE Name = 'name_to_be_checked' AND Gender = 'gender_to_be_checked' AND Age = age_to_checked`, if 0 rows then return false else true.